# Controlling fan speed

Tags: arduino

I want to control an intel 4-wire fan with arduino. I have connected up the wires and tried to code pasted below, but the fan keeps changing speeds on the slow setting, and I am not sure why. The only thing I dont have is a resistor between the arduino and the control pin on the fan.

```
const int PWMPin = 3;
int pinOUT = 7;
int pinIN = 4;


void setup() {

pinMode(PWMPin, OUTPUT); 

TCCR2A = 0x23;

TCCR2B = 0x0A;

OCR2A = 79;  

pinMode(pinOUT, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(pinOUT, HIGH);
pinMode(pinIN, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

 switch (digitalRead(pinIN)) {
 case HIGH:
  OCR2B = 80; 
  break;
 default:
  OCR2B = 20; 
 break;
 }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem looks more likely to be in the electronics than in the code—have you considered asking on http://arduino.stackexchange.com?

Comment: UnbescholtenerBuerger answered the problem further down. It was indeed the electronics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't spot any errors in your code. How do you toggle the fan's speed, or in other words: What does your circuit that is hooked up to pin 4 look like? Because it sounds like you are missing a pulldown resistor. The input voltage does not vary between 'High / 5V' and 'Low / 0V', but rather between 'High 5V' and 'Undefined / 0-5V Noise'.

Assuming that you have a button/switch/whatever hooked up to P4 that connects P4 and Vin when pressed, try this: Put a 10K resistor between P4 and GND.

This shouldn't be an answer, but I still lack the reputation necessary to comment, so there you go.

Comment: This did it! I originally had a 1k resistor between the arduino and the input pin on the fan, but I took it away and forgot about it.

I now put a 10k between pin4, which is the button INPUT pin on the arduino and ground.